# Number of rows within each window

Tags: python-polars

I have some expressions that I will evaluate later either within or without a window function. This normally works fine. Have `pl.col("x").max()`—add `.over("y")` later. Have `pl.arange(0, pl.count())`—add `.over("y")` later. One expression this does not work on is `pl.count()`.

If you try to window `pl.count()`, Polars errors:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,1,0,0], y=[1,2,3,4]))
expression = pl.count()

df.with_columns([expression.over("x").alias("z")])
# exceptions.ComputeError: Cannot apply a window function, did not find a root column. This is likely due to a syntax error in this expression: count()
```

Is there a version of `count` that can handle being windowed? I know that I can do `pl.col("x").count().over("x")`, but then I have to know ahead of time what columns will exist, and the expressions and the window columns come from completely different parts of my code.

Comment: And no, `pl.repeat(1, pl.count()).count()` does not work either. The Rust code panics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Polars >=0.14. Starting in that release, the behavior in the original question started working without modification.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,1,0,0], y=[1,2,3,4]))
expression = pl.count()

df.with_columns([expression.over("x").alias("z")])
# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
# │ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
# │ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
# │ 0   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   │
# │ 0   ┆ 4   ┆ 2   │
# └─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the limitation of `window` expressions is that they need to have a root column. This means a column that starts the expression that is in the `Dataframe`'s context. `pl.count()` is an expression that does not refer to any column, and is generic over any column.

We can easily circumvent this limitation with the knowledge that `column.len() == count()`. So we can just take the `first()` column in the `DataFrame`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,1,0,0], y=[1,2,3,4]))
expression = pl.first().len()

df.with_columns([expression.over("x").alias("z")])
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 4   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need it to be a window, but based on the example that you've given a simple `groupby` would suffice

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,1,0,0], y=[1,2,3,4]))
expression = pl.count()

print(df.groupby(pl.col("x")).agg(expression))
# print(df.select([expression]))
# ^this would work on the whole dataframe
```